# How to Retrieve and Add to list item property bag using csom sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, development, csom

is there a way to add and retrieve values from the property bag of a list item using CSOM? I am using sharepoint 2013, all my searches come up empty for the list item, and I know in sharepoint 2010 it was not posible.

I would very much like to know if it can be done and how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's not possible. [`ListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem_members.aspx) class doesn't expose any property or method to operate on property bag.

Answer (score 1):

Get Property

```
var lst= ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(lst, l => l.RootFolder.Properties);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var value = lst.RootFolder.Properties[key];
```

Set Property

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var lstProps= list.RootFolder.Properties;
lstProps[key] = value;
lst.RootFolder.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: That is for list property, I am looking for list item property bag